# Use of [shooting] and [guns]

Tags: discussion, tags

These two tags seem very similar:

> [shooting](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shooting): Shooting is the act or process of firing firearms. Use this tag for questions relating to the shooting for sport or shooting for hunting purposes.
>
> [guns](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guns): Questions referring to use of firearms.

Should these tags be merged? Or should these tags coexist with a clear distinction between them?

One could argue that [shooting](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shooting) is used for question really about the shooting process whereas [guns](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guns) could be used for more general questions about guns (storage, best practices on carrying, etc.) In that case, I think the tag description should be clarified and some questions may need to be retagged.

Comment: I have been working on this just going slow so not to overwhelm the front page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say they are different enough to be separate tags,

- This one [Storing hunting firearms and ammo in a safe not designed for them?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/18992/storing-hunting-firearms-and-ammo-in-a-safe-not-designed-for-them) is about firearms and not shooting.
- While this one [What is a "shooting jacket"?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/6171/what-is-a-shooting-jacket)  is about shooting but not really about guns.

With that said this topic could probably use some cleanup and some more tags.

- Add [rifle](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rifle) , [pistol](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pistol) and [airgun](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airgun)  tags like we already have in [shotgun](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shotgun)
- Go through each and just see if the tags make sense.
- Rewrite the tag wikis, to make the distinction more clear.

Comment: If you do decide to make all those tags, I recommend putting a line in the excerpt mentioning the other related tags. That way, users know what they can choose from. I'm not sure if it's actually need to create that many tags though, it can actually decrease findability if there are very few questions tagged with them. Or do you think they should be tagged one of those suggestions in addition to the general [guns] tag?

Comment: @JJJ In this case, it would make sense to leave the general tag in addition to adding the specific tag

Comment: That seems sensible, I then suggest mentioning the [guns] tag in each of the sub tags and vice versa (so all sub tags are mentioned in the last sentence of the excerpt of the parent tag).